# print(os.listdir()) prints non-existent (old) files when using

Tags: python, macos, operating-system

I am testing the different functionalities of importing os. I am using a Mac and all I typed was code to change the working directory to Desktop and print the list of directories available. When I run the program the IDE (Pycharm in this case) prints non-existent files (some deleted files and others relocated to new locations). Some of the ones that don't exist are printed with a weird format as the initial two characters are replaced by `"~$"` (example: `'~$rtfolio.docx'`).

```
import os

os.chdir("/Users/me/Desktop")


print(os.listdir())
```

Comment: Are you sure the "non-existent" files don't exist? What happens if you type `cat <filename>` in the console?

Comment: @dio  Do you mean the "Python console"? I have never used that before and don't know what it does. Can you elaborate?

Comment: No, I mean the console. As in, the command line. Like... the place where you run your Python files.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have hidden files in Desktop that you don't see as a normal user.  Try Command + Shift + . to see them, and try creating a new folder and see if you get the same error if you test the new folder.

Comment: This worked! I can see them now. If I delete these hidden files, will I also delete their originals? Also, is this normal? If not how do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Terrific.  It's normal Mac OS behavior so I would not touch those files unless you really need to.  Mac OS hides them so that users don't mess with them.  You're better off making your own folder.  Could you accept my answer?

Comment: So I should leave even the ones created by Microsoft software? Some are pretty useless as I don't even need the originals. Also what do you mean by "making my own folder"? you mean create a new folder and add them to that folder?

Comment: Sometimes it's fine to delete hidden files, but you could mess things up, so unless you have some need to do it, just let the computer administer itself.  By a new folder, I was thinking you want to create a folder for testing your code or something.  If instead you want to explore whatever is in the Desktop directory, then no need to create a folder, just ignore the hidden files.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have just created a new folder where I have put all the hidden files (that I can see because some - I assume the most crucial ones- I can't even see when I enable viewing hidden files) and relocated the folder to reduce clutter on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

os.listdir() appears to be revealing files that are normally hidden.

Filenames beginning with ~$ are temporary (hidden) files used by Microsoft software including Word and Excel

Comment: Yeah these are mostly Microsoft software documents. There are exceptions though : '.DS_Store' , '.localized', '.png'

Answer (score 0):

When Microsoft Word is used to open documents, it creates temporary lock files with this sort of format. If another user were to try to open the same file (on a shared network, for example), this lock would prevent this.

This is noted [here](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1075940), for example.

You should be able to see these files if you enable viewing hidden files.